# Automatic part number creation, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, userform

I am trying to create a userform that outputs a part number into a text box, after inputting the relevant data in the format of `.25X2.00X2.50`. I am having issues with keeping the trailing zeros to two places (even if the data added has no trailing zeros or more than two) and keeping the "X" in between the values. Below is a small portion of the code I have, which keeps giving me `25X2X25`. Any pointers or advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim AngleThicknessRound As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(AngleThicknessRound).ToString(AngleThickness.Text)
Dim AngleLeg1Round As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(AngleLeg1Round).ToString(AngleLeg1.Text)
Dim AngleLeg2Round As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(Math.Round(AngleLeg2Round, 2)).ToString(AngleLeg2.Text)
ShapeAdd.Text = AngleThicknessRound & "X" & AngleLeg1Round & "X" & AngleLeg2Round
```

Comment: You should be parsing the text not the the newly created variable. `Dim AngleLeg1Round As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(AngleLeg1.Text)`. And `Decimal.TryParse` is even better.

Comment: You seem to be unaware of what data types you're working with and when. It seems you're calling `Decimal.Parse()` often for values that _are already number types_. **NEVER** do that. You're also calling `.ToString()` and then assigning the result to a Decimal type. **NEVER** do that. When working with .Net, it's _very important_ to be aware of the data type of any variable or value you're working with, and the code here shows a complete lack of understanding in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the extra `ToString()` calls in the first section. Even if those arguments contain valid format strings, you don't want to use them at this time, when you're still assigning the results to a decimal value.

Additionally, `Math.Round()` is already working with numbers. Why would you think you need to use `Decimal.Parse()` when you already have a number? You do have `Option Strict` turned on, right? RIGHT!?

And once we simplify that out of the code, what's up with these self-referencing variable declarations?

```
Dim AngleThicknessRound As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(AngleThicknessRound)
Dim AngleLeg1Round As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(AngleLeg1Round)
Dim AngleLeg2Round As Decimal = Math.Round(AngleLeg2Round, 2)
```

But let's assume you have all of this sorted out, and turn our attention to setting the `ShapeAdd.Text` value. What you really want here is to use the `String.Format()` method:

```
ShapeAdd.Text = String.Format("{0:#.00}X{1:#.00}X{2:#.00}", AngleThicknessRound, AngleLeg1Round, AngleLeg2Round)
```

Take a look at the [String.Format documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [Custom Numeric Format String documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) for how that all works.